# What happens to the maximun operating ratings when the device is unpowered?

Tags: operational-amplifier, ac, single-supply-op-amp

I have a circuit with an OpAmp and a current transformer. My circuit applies a DC bias to the CT to be able to process the signal with an OpAmp with a single power supply, because the CT provides an AC signal. So far, so good.

I am wondering about what happens when the circuit is unpowered but the CT is still connected. In this case I don't have a DC bias, so I could have ±1V RMS at the OpAmp input pin and [its datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opa344.pdf) clearly specifies that absolute maximum ratings are -0.5V and Vcc+0.5V. This is not a problem when I have the DC bias working, but it will disappear when power is off.

So the question is simple: what happens with this circuit when unpowered but the current transformer is still providing an AC signal?

Should I do something like adding a FET in parallel to the current transformer to short-circuit the CT when no power is available?

I am concerned about the OpAmp health and the transient at switch on/off.

Comment: what are specs for CT and R.burden and Vdd?

Answer (score 7):

You are right, when the circuit is unpowered the CT output could violate the absolute maximum ratings of the opamp.  This is not good.

The protection diodes will be forward biased, and the power rail partially powered.  This might be OK, depending on what is connected to the opamp power and what exactly the datasheet says about this.  It might be acceptable to add diodes in series with the opamp power leads so that the ±1 V on the input pins doesn't try to power up the whole power net.  If you do this, make sure to put the bypass capacitors on the opamp side of the diodes.

However, a simple fix is to use a CT with half the gain.  Now it will produce only ±500 mV signals, which the opamp can handle when powered down.  You've got a amplifier in there anyway, so ±500 mV should be good enough unless you're doing something unusual.

Answer (score 3):

You should add enough series resistance to limit the input current to less than 10mA. You can exceed the +/-0.5V if you limit the current.

[image]

I suggest limiting it to **well** under 10mA so any spikes will not cause problems. In fact, limiting the current to less than 10mA at the point where the CT **saturates** is exactly what I would do, because you may not be able to control what current flows through the CT primary under all possible conditions.

You could also use Schottky diodes such as BAT54 to shunt current away from the inputs, but such diodes tend to be leaky (possibly affecting accuracy) and you still have to ensure that the current is suitably limited.

Note the recommendation to limit input negative voltage under operational conditions. This could cause **start-up issues** if you don't add the Schottky diode to ground in addition to limiting the current. The suggested 1N5818 has more leakage than the BAT54, but has a better chance of limiting the voltage. You might want to seriously consider using a different op-amp without this latch-up 'feature' if this is a complication. It's the sort of thing that can cause you to pull your hair out with field problems.

Comment: Could an "ordinary" diode clamp combined with a resistor be used to limit the clamping current seen by the chip without adding leakage?  Even if the internal diode only has a 0.5V drop and the external clamping diode has a 0.8V drop, a 1K series resistor would limit the chip's clamping current to 300uA.

Answer (score 2):

The absolute maximum ratings for current into the op-amp's inputs states 10 mA and here's where this helps. If you don't feed the output of the CT directly into the op-amp input pin but instead, feed via a 1 kohm resistor, you will only potentially exceed the input current if the peak voltage from the CT exceeded 10 volts. You can of course choose a resistor that is significantly bigger than 1 kohm; I was just giving an example.

Other than that you are quite right to be cautious in this situation. Looking further into the data sheet this becomes clear: -

[image]

So, I would follow the recommendations shown.

Comment: 25 seconds late..

Comment: Ah dear boy, that statement may only be valid for the first minute after posting.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when Vin exceeds supply rail by 0.5V? Nothing until  the supply turns on and then the CMOS OA turns into an SCR crowbar across the supply rail if the condition still exists triggering an inherent PNPN substrate which is an SCR. and draws as much current as possible, possibly frying it , until current is removed from supply. ( read about *CMOS latchup*)

**You must specify your input environment and worst case transient** with CT, Rb etc before you start ANY design. In spite of this missing info... here are a few ideas.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvHcvL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is one of dozens of solutions.

In this example I use the source current to bootstrap the supply via D1,2 to prevent latch-up and current limit with 100k. This of course adds temporary burden to the CT and saturation may cause be an issue, which invalidates this option , same for a Zener clamp.

ALWAYS SPECIFY WORST CASE TRANSIENT INPUT v,i,t AND ADJUST DESIGN TO PROTECT ALL INPUTS AND OUTPUTS BELOW ABSOLUTE MAX.

Op Amp Iq is < 150uA @5V thus Req=6k7.  The 1uF absorbs input transients due to impedance ratio. U1 input is diode clamped internally but diode is limited to 10mA unlike external BAT54 which supports 100mA @0.5V

Comment: Your design is very similar to what I am using now. The diodes to limit the range are a good idea and the resistor in the input helps to avoid dangerous current. I have to think about this. Thanks for your time.

I am wondering about the effect pursued with the two capacitors. Could you explain a little bit more?. I am not an electrical engineer and my knowledge of electronics is good "in theory" (I am engineer in a different area) but I have little actual practice. Explanations like "input transients due to impedance ratio"... I understand the individual words but no the global mission. Thx

Comment: caps are like shocks to wheel bumps

Comment: Do you see any need to protect U2 too?. I understand that the problem is U1 because the voltage generated in R1 and that doesn't affect U2. Just wondering if I am right :-). Thanks!

Comment: Tony, I understand the concept. Many transient issues are solved with a cap. But I rather prefer to understand the reason for each component in the design. I don't see the point of C2. It could help to "slow start" U2 at power on, but could be an issue (vin > vcc) at power down. Since you are the expert and I am feeling shame of my analog electronic knowledge, I want to learn from you! :)

Comment: U2 shud be a BJT type like LM324 which has lower output impedance and fewer issues like CMOS OA's